# User not able to log back into windows, offline, after local admin logged in using previously chached credentials

Tags: login

I ran into a situation a little while ago where I, as a local admin on a corporate domain, had to get into a user's laptop while the user was unavailable.  I had previously established cached credentials while online at the office, so I was able to do so.  When I logged out of my account, and had the user log back in, the laptop wouldn't let the user log back in giving a "cannot find domain" error.  As soon as the user was back in the office and hardwired to the network, the user was able to log in normally.

The corporate enterprise environment uses Windows XP Pro SP2 as a base image for the various user level computers on the network.

My question is...

Is this a Microsoft setting/issue, or is this a coporate environment issue?  I don't have access to non-corporate laptops to test this, and have never heard of this particular scenario occuring before.

Any thoughts?

To recap / test:

Laptop user logged in online.
Local admin user logged in online.
Laptop user offsite and offline, locks windows.
Local admin overrides user account, logs in as local admin while offline.
Local admin logs out of windows.
Laptop user can not log back into laptop offline, even after rebooting machine.

Again, I'm mostly looking to see if this is common across different Enterprise environments, and to see if this is more of a Microsoft thing, or a specific Enterprise network/environment thing.

If anyone has any thoughts on this I would be very inter

Comment: ...sorry, cut of last sentence:
If anyone has any thoughts on this I would be very interested to read them.

Comment: Found a solution.  Microsoft KB888516 describes the issue better than I did and will most likely resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft KB888516 did in fact resolve the issue.

This can be closed now.

Comment: Well, good catch then.

Answer (score 0):

You may be limiting, either via local GPO or domain GPO, how many cached credentials the workstation is configured to store.

Comment: That particular laptop had 2.  Others in the same company, training machines, have had 100+